# Anonymous method referencing local variables throws run-time error

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

C# .Net 3.5 I get a list of images, make a copy, provide an empty list, instantiate a xaml Dialog which has an event, OnNameChanged, which is `Action<ILMWorkOrderImage>`.  The following code builds, but, at run-time, throws a null reference exception on the second statement, the assignment to m_OriginalList.  If I skip that, it throws a null reference exception on the next statement, a simple assignment of a new list!  These two variables are referenced in the anonymous method that handles the OnNameChanged event.  If I define m_OriginalList and m_WithNameChanges as member variables, all is well.  I commonly use local variables in my anonymous methods; do you see some reason that it wouldn't work this time?

```
List<ILMWorkOrderImage> workOrderImages = wo.GetImages( );
// Copy the list for comparison later
List<ILMWorkOrderImage> m_OriginalList = new List<ILMWorkOrderImage>( workOrderImages );
List<ILMWorkOrderImage> m_WithNameChanges = new List<ILMWorkOrderImage>( );
AddPicturesDialog dlg2 = new AddPicturesDialog( context, workOrderImages );
dlg2.OnNameChanged += ( ILMWorkOrderImage _ChangedWOI ) => 
{
    if ( m_OriginalList.Contains( _ChangedWOI ) && !m_WithNameChanges.Contains( _ChangedWOI ) )
    {
        m_WithNameChanges.Add( _ChangedWOI );
    }
};
if ( true == dlg2.ShowDialog( ) )...
```

Comment: Why are you comparing the result of `ShowDialog` to `true` instead of to `DialogResult.OK`?

Comment: You get an exception running `m_WithNameChanges = new List<ILMWorkOrderImage>( );`?

Comment: This is a WPF Window, not a WinForms Window.  In this case, ShowDialog( ) returns bool.

Comment: Yes I get an exception running the assignment to m_WithNameChanges.  That's what finally pushed us into looking at the anonymous method, which, when we commented it out, the run-time error went away.  It made no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to chalk this one up to the Debugger (VS 2008).  The code I presented was in the seventh case of a switch statement:  I had set a breakpoint at the top of the switch, and was jumping down to this particular case.  When I quit doing that, the problem went away.  Also, if I put the code outside the switch (and didn't use a breakpoint), it ran OK. I also found that, even in Debug, if I pulled the code out into a method and had the case statement just execute the method, I was OK there, too.  And (thanks to everyone for looking), I found that, although I could reproduce this behavior in this app all day long, I could not reproduce it in a little console app.

Comment: Glad to hear you have a workaround. Your suspicion has merit. I had also begun to consider the IDE as a cause. But I kept reminding myself this isn't VS6, that is all behind us ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the second statement to:

```
List<ILMWorkOrderImage> m_OriginalList = new List<ILMWorkOrderImage>(workOrderImages);
```

Comment: I still have the same problem, but I like your cleaner code; I was apparently in love with linq :)